# Inviting facebook friends to an application

Tags: facebook-graph-api, invite, facebook-invite

I'm creating an application where in I'm creating stories. So for each stories I want to invite my facebook friends to collaborate something. So which is the best way to invite? Is it `apprequest` or `send` method. Please help me some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this Facebook concept [article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/requests/), Facebook recommends Application request (i.e. `apprequests` ).

1. The recipient is a **friend** of the sender and has **not installed** the game. This is considered an invite.
2. The recipient is a **friend** of the sender and has **installed** the game.
3. The recipient has **installed** the game. In this case the sender and recipient do not need to be friends.

---

On the other hand, [send request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) is used to share information to other user.

**Conclusion**

Therefore, `apprequests` should be used.

Comment: But it sends only one time. I needed for each story I want to send invitation. So that time how can I do it?

Comment: use App Request Dialog. It can select up to 50 friends.